# Hibernate en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate, delete

Tengo un proyecto java con Ant en Netbeans 12.0 con Hibernate a una base de datos mysql, exactamente a la base de datos que te da como ejemplo, sakila.
Estoy intentando eliminar un registro de la tabla actor, pero en los pojos que me ha generado la configuración de hibernate, exactamente en actor.java me ha generado únicamente:

```
 public Actor(String firstName, String lastName, Date lastUpdate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
    public Actor(String firstName, String lastName, Date lastUpdate, Set filmActors) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
       this.filmActors = filmActors;
    }
```

He pensado en utilizar el primero y solicitar al usuario, el nombre, apellido y fecha de última modificación para identificar el registro a eliminar ya que no lo ha preparado para hacerlo por el identificador que hubiera sido lo ideal:

```
public static void borrar_actor() throws ParseException{
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del actor o actriz a eliminar:");
        String firstName = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el apellido del actor o actriz a eliminar:");
        String lastName = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de última actualización (yyyy-MM-dd):");
        String lastUpdateStr = sc.next();

        Transaction tx=null;
        Session sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx=sesion.beginTransaction(); 

        // Utilizar SimpleDateFormat para analizar la cadena de fecha sin hora
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(lastUpdateStr);
                Timestamp lastUpdateTimestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
                
        //System.out.println(lastUpdateTimestamp);
        Actor a = new Actor(firstName,lastName,lastUpdateTimestamp);
        sesion.delete(a);
        System.out.println("Actor borrado");
        tx.commit();        

        System.out.println("Presione Enter para volver al menú.");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    }
```

Al ejecutarlo, no salta ninguna excepción, pero no me lo borra, se queda "running" y me aparece en el output:

```
ene 15, 2024 12:27:41 PM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener deleteTransientEntity
INFO: HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing
```

¿Sabe alquién qué puede estar pasando y cómo solucionarlo? Muchas gracias.